# Spring Boot custom login page displays 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, freemarker

Hi I'm currently trying to set up a simple login page using Spring Boot Security but whenever I try to access the login view I get a 404 "page not found" error.

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("admin").roles("ADMIN");
}
}
```

Login view, using freemarker (located at main/resources/templates/login.ftl):

```
<body class="login">
<div>
<div class="login_wrapper">
    <div class="animate form login_form">
        <section class="login_content">
            <form>
                <h1>Login Form</h1>
                <div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a class="btn btn-default submit" href="/units">Log in</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do you have a dependency on Freemarker in your pom.xml or Gradle file?

Comment: Yup `compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a view controller for /login. either write a controller for that or following will do.

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("package_name")
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }
}
```

To setup view rosolver:

```
@Bean  
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {  
InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();  
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");  
    resolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
    return resolver;  
}
```

Now put your ftl files inside webapp/WEB-INF/pages directory. You're all set.

Comment: I don't think I have, I was using this https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ as a guide.

Comment: So I should create a webapp/WEB-INF directory to put my login view in?

Comment: yup, you need to create that.

Comment: you need to have a look on spring mvc standard directory structure for maven or gradle.